# Can i delegate writeTo() to another MessageBodyWriter in JAX-RS?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, resteasy

Consider a wrapping and wrapped objects, such as :

```
new Living( new Person () ), new Dead ( new Animal () ), ...  //pseudocode
```

And i have a `MessageBodyWriter` for `Dead` and `Living`, that after doing its job (say returning 404 for Dead) needs to delegate `writeTo()`  to the `MessageBodyWriter` for `Person`and `Animal`.

Is there a way to query JAX-RS implementations for MessageBodyWriters or submit objects down the chain?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Generally you can retrieve a specific `MessageBodyWriter` by querying `Providers#getMessageBodyWriter` which you can `@Inject` in another `MessageBodyWriter` instance, but it's not a `MessageBodyWriter`'s job to throw any 404 errors, that's the resource's job.

Comment: I see, Providers#getMessageBodyWriter or @Inject sounds excelent, i'll look it up in the spec. I understand that should be the resources responsibility, i'll try to move it there, nice point. But there are other situations that delegating "parts" to other writers will be helpful. Thanks!